# Mostrar select por defecto

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Muy buen día, tengo un problema, quisiera que se me muestre el en el select la opción por defecto pero sucede que si pongo las directivas de Angular, no se me muestra la opción por defecto, pero si quito esto, si me aparece la opción por defecto.

Aquí está el código:

```
<select class="custom-select" ng-change="ctrl.precancelacion(detalle, $index, detalle.riesgoEstado.id)" ng-model="detalle.riesgoEstado.id">
           <option value="1" selected>Activo</option>
           <option value="5">Pagado</option>
           <option value="6">Precancelado</option>
           <option value="7">Abono</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ¿Definiste el valor de `detalle.riesgoEstado.id` desde tu controller?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código en el que defines `detalle.riesgoEstado`? Es allí donde debes cambiarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias a los que me respondieron, el problema se solucionó creando un array de objetos  con los valores que tenía en los options y mostrándoles usando la directiva ng-options y pasando los valores ahí ☺️

Answer (score -2):

```
selected="True"
```

para que estè seleccionado debes indicarle el valor en true

Comment: A parte de que ese valor para esa propiedad no es válido, no soluciona el problema ya que está usando un marco de trabajo llamado "angular.js", así que hay que hacer cambios en el código para conseguir lo que desea.